# static_cast from Derived* to void* to Base*

Tags: c++, static-cast

I would like to cast a pointer to a member of a derived class to `void*` and from there to a pointer of the base class, like in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
       void function1(){std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;}
       virtual void function2()=0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
       virtual void function2(){std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    void ptr* = static_cast<void*>(&d);
    Base* baseptr=static_cast<Base*>(ptr);
    baseptr->function1();
    baseptr->function2(); 
}
```

This compiles and gives the desired result (prints `1` and `2` respectively), but is it guaranteed to work? The description of `static_cast` I found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast
only mentions conversion to `void*` and back to a pointer to the *same* class (point 10).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the general case, converting a base to void to derived (or vice versa) via static casting is not safe.

There will be cases where it will almost certainly work: if everything involved is a pod, or standard layout, and only single inheritance is involved, then things should be fine, at least in practice: I do not have chapter and verse from the standard, but the general idea is that the base in that case is guaranteed to be the prefix of the derived, and they will share addresses.

If you want to start seeing this fail, mix in `virtual` inheritance, multiple inheritance (both `virtual` and not), and multiple implementation inheritance that are non trivial.  Basically when the address of the different type views of `this` differ, the `void` cast from and back to a different type is doomed.  I have seen this fail in practice, and the fact it can fail (due to changes in your code base far away from the point of casting) is why you want to be careful about *always* casting to and from void pointer with the exact same type.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no, it is not safe.

Suppose that casting `Derived*` directly to `Base*` results in a different address (for example, if multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance is involved).

Now if you inserted a cast to `void*` in between, how would the compiler know how to convert that `void*` to an appropriate `Base*` address?

If you need to cast a `Derived*` to a `void*`, you should explicitly cast the `void*` back to the original `Derived*` type first. (And from there, the cast from `Derived*` to `Base*` is implicit anyway, so you end up with the same number of casts, and thus it's not actually any less convenient.)

Answer (score 0):

From the link you supplied yourself

> 9) A pointer to member of some class D can be upcast to a pointer to member of its base class B. This static_cast makes no checks to ensure the member actually exists in the runtime type of the pointed-to object.

Meaning as long as you know that the upcast is safe before you do it it is guaranteed to work. That's why you should be using `dynamic_cast` which returns `nullptr` if unsuccessful.

Think of it this way if you have.

```
Type * t1;
```

`static_cast` of t1 to one of the classes deriving from it cannot be known at compile time, without in depth analysis of your program (which obviously it is not and should not be doing), so even if it ends up being correct you have no way of checking. `dynamic_cast` does extra work at runtime to check if the conversion was successful hence the prefix dynamic.

Comment: but I am doing an upcast (towards the base). I know this is always safe, but I'm worried about the casting to `void*` in between

Comment: @Roberto if you know that it is a valid cast then it is safe, if the cast has a chance of failing it's not safe

Comment: I know that `static_cast<Base*>(Derived*)` is safe - are you saying that then, also `static_cast<Base*>(static_cast<void*>(Derived*))` is safe?

Comment: @Roberto well it's not safe in the sense that it gives no error code if it fails

Comment: Any comment on the DV

Comment: This answer talks about downcasting and using `dynamic_cast`, neither of which is relevant to the question.  The statement about "`static_cast` of t1 to one of it's [sic] bases cannot be known at compile time" is nonsensical; you can always implicitly cast from a derived class to its base class!

Comment: @jamesdlin sorry that last part is a typo I meant to write cast to one of the classes deriving from it

Comment: @jamesdlin fixed it, I just mixed up the upcast and downcast words for some reason

Comment: Sorry, but this still does not address the question; it does not discuss the intermediate cast through a `void*` pointer at all.  And again, `dynamic_cast` is not relevant here.